# How to re-size image in wordpress template

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am using a wordpress template to control my website.  On the home page is a small header with "Home About Us Contact Us" etc etc and then below that is an image that transitions to another image which transitions to another image.  This image is too large for my liking so I am trying to shrink it.  So I go to the CSS and adjust the image size, however because there is text on the bottom of the image it is being cut off.

I would like to maintain the image width but just make it a little shorter, say about 75% of the original design.

Below is what I think is the applicable code

```
.camera_wrap {
    height: 672px!important;
    max-width: 1920px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 60px!important;
```

I added the `height: 672px!important;` code which makes it about the height I want but again the bottom gets cut off.  I would prefer to have the CSS re-size the image instead of clip it.  But all of my searches haven't turned up how to do this.  I am just finding the  re-size attribute.

Comment: I'd never put a fixed height to an image, maybe `min-height` or `max-height`, if you're using height, use percentages or other relative units, that will work well on responsive. Also if you can make a fiddle it will be great.

Comment: great ill look into max-height, thank you.  If it works ill have you put it into an answer so i can accept it.  I am sure this is basic but I am a programmer that got stuck doing some HTML..... grrrr.  But thanks

Comment: No problem, it's just that fixing heights (especially with `!important`), should be avoided. Another option is to put the image in the background of the div, and use `background-size:cover` to cover the entire div.

Comment: So what i tried is `max-height: 10%!important;` and it has no effect?  I know my method especially the `!important` is not usually acceptable style but they just want this done. I can go back later to override it with CSS properly but I just can't take the time right now. But why did my max-height not have an effect, any idea?

Comment: If you can recreate it in a fiddle we can probably help you find an exact solution. http://jsfiddle.net/ or codepen or wherever

Comment: I will look up what a fiddle is and do so, give me a few

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ it's a place where you can try to recreate the issue you have, and then we can see what can be done to fix it. In order for percentage to work, you need to be able to compare it to some element. 10% by itself doesn't mean a thing, but 10% of containers height does :)

Comment: @dingo_d Oh I see that makes sense. Am I able to use a percentage of the image height?

Comment: you might have to use the class of the container div and then the img to affect change.. `.image-div img { css: here; }` if you have a bunch of images in one div you can use nth-child to get at the specific image you are wanting to play with. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: YES! That is perfect, could you put that into an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a path to the img rather than the images class to control the styling for the image.

example html

```
<div class="image-div">
    <img class="image">
</div>
```

instead of

```
.image { height: 500px; }
```

try

```
.image-div img { height: 500px; }
```

Also, here's an example of a fiddle and an example in that fiddle of how to affect change to only the second image using nth-child

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/g6m5nqc9/1/

```
.image:nth-child(n+2) {
    height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: I added this `.camera_wrap img {
 max-height: 75%;
 max-width: none!important;
}` but now there is a large gap between the picture and the text below.  [here](http://gyazo.com/7a801fa69c61f0688a685e042a9b84c4) is a screen shot.  What did i do wrong?

Comment: Hmm, screenshot link doesn't seem to have come through. I'll check back in 10 if nobodies answered by then.

Comment: I corrected the screen shot.  I "inspected element" in Chrome and I think what is going on is that there is a enclosing div. `<div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="camera_wrap_1" style="display: block; height: 232px;"><div class="camera_fakehover">` that is taking up that space.... Can you have parent elements shrink to fit its children, if that makes sense?

Comment: If you set the element to `display: table;` it should fit it's children precisely, assuming there is no other styling applied to it, like that inline style where `height:232px` is added. But I can't tell what the problem is here exactly, I didn't get a lot out of that image, sorry. It definitely seems like the coding can be simplified to suit your needs but I assume this is a theme made by somebody else.

Comment: I stopped being lazy and found that `display: table;` method on another stack exchange and it worked perfect.  Thank you so much sir. +1 and accepted.

Comment: I see now that it appears to be a slideshow plugin or the slideshow is built into the theme. If its a plugin check in WP admin Plugins - editor. There will be a lot of styling in there and somewhere from there is where that inline style is being injected from, if you find the inline style to be the problem overriding your css.